# WPF - Dynamic object from json to datagrid

Tags: c#, json, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.5

I've got this problem:

I read from web a json result from a query and after I wish load it into a `DataGrid` object.

Here is my code:

```
void readData()
{
  var client = new HttpClient();

  HttpResponseMessage Response = await client.GetAsync("http://goo.gl/3LbKQy");
  int statusCode = (int)Response.StatusCode;
  string results = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results);
  myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

but my grid contains the rows empty.. my guess is that the dynamic data doesn't allow to obtain the fields info on datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ItemsSource value needs to implement IEnumerable and the DataGrid will probably struggle to auto-generate columns as reflection does not work well with dynamic types.

Comment: Can you explain more?